# React-helmet metaTags are disappears on page change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-helmet

I made small learning ReactJS based Server Side app. My goal is to share a dynamic post on facebook using React SSR, I have made canvas based app it generates image and I want to set dynamic metaTags to share post on FB.

here my sample code 
[gitRepo](https://github.com/amit0shakya/reactfbshare),

I am also facing One more issue when I change page automatically using history.push or Redirect tag in Render, then Rect-helmet won't set metaTags.

Comment: Please provide code showing where and how you are setting the meta. We don't want too crawl through your repo looking for it.

Comment: @Dominic, I have set metaTags like <Helmet
                    title="Only4Laugh"
                    meta={[
                        {property: 'og:url', content: 'https://amit0shakyafbshare.herokuapp.com'},
                        {property: 'og:type', content: 'website'},
                        {property: 'og:title', content: 'Amit Post Title'},
                        {property: 'og:description', content: 'Amit Post Discription'},
                        {property: 'og:image', content: imagepath},
                    ]} />

Comment: @Dominic, It works Properly when I set metaTags but issue is When I change page then MetaTags are Disapper from head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're setting meta on one page (Project) bizarrely after a POST request is successful. Is it any wonder it doesn't exist in other routes? React helmet calculates the meta dynamically from the react tree, like any React code if it doesn't exist at that point it gets removed.

If you want to share meta across pages then set it higher up e.g. App.js which all routes share.

Also you're setting it after a `saveImage` request, not sure if those meta tags will be useful when set at that point.

Comment: Yes, Actually after image save, I have successfully generate image and uploaded after then I need to share it to facebook, What I did first user draw something then click on save image then it changes head with metaTags, then I want to change page which will contains metaTags in biggining and facebook crawler can easily read those metaTags. So what can be best way to do this...???

Comment: If you want to keep that logic in Project, then you should save the data to generate the meta in a store e.g. redux store, and something higher up e.g. App.js should be responsible for generating the helmet meta render code

Comment: So saveImage -> update store with meta data -> App.js gets re-rendered with meta changes, and since it is in global store other pages will also have it. I see you don't have a global store yet but you will probably need one for other functionality anyway.

Comment: I face one more thing, when we add metaTags using react-helmet, it sets after page render, So that's why I am adding metaTags before page change, that's why I directly tries to set after save Image.

Comment: I dn't able to find any working sample with Dynamic share with ReactJS to facebook.  I dn't know how to achieve this...

Comment: Finally I use react-meta-tags instead of react-helmet, It help me to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use react-meta-tags instead of react-helmet, It helps me to fix this issue